# Flutter Bad State: No Element

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, rss

I am trying to develop an application that displays a news feed from several RSS feeds, however, before it loads completely, there is the Bad State: No Element error.

First, here's the beginning of the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:mitech/controllers/bookmarked_posts_controller.dart';
import 'package:mitech/models/bookmarked_posts_model.dart';
import 'package:webfeed/webfeed.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  const Feed({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String title = 'Últimas atualizações';

  @override
  State<Feed> createState() => _FeedState();
}

class _FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  static const String placeholderImg = 'assets/images/noImage.jpg';
  late GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshKey;

  List<Uri> feedURIs = [
    Uri(
      scheme: 'https',
      host: 'rss.tecmundo.com.br',
      path: 'feed'
    ),
  ];

  List<RssFeed> feeds = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
    load();
  }
```

To get the feed:

```
Future<List<RssFeed>?> loadFeed() async {
    try {
      final client = http.Client();
      
      for (Uri uri in feedURIs) {
        final response = await client.get(uri);
        feeds.add(RssFeed.parse(response.body));
      }

      return feeds;
    } catch (e) {
      //
    }
    return null;
  }

  load() async {
    loadFeed().then((result) {
      if (null == result || result.toString().isEmpty) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Erro ao carregar.'),
              content: const Text('Tente novamente mais tarde.'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        );
      }
      updateFeed(result);
    });
  }

  updateFeed(feed) {
    setState(() {
      feeds = feed;
    });
  }
```

Now, the code to open the news, as well as the sfunctions that show the title, subtitle and the image of the news.

```
Future<void> openFeed (String url) async {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if(!await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView)) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Erro ao carregar.'),
            content: const Text('Tente novamente mais tarde.'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }

  Text title (title) {
    return Text(
      title,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      ),
      maxLines: 2,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      key: ValueKey('$title'),
    );
  }

  Text subtitle (subtitle) {
    return Text(
      subtitle ?? '',
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
      ),
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      key: ValueKey('$subtitle'),
    );
  }

  Padding thumbnail (imageUrl) {
    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey('$imageUrl'),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
      child: imageUrl != null ? CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(placeholderImg),
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ) :
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        child: Image.asset(placeholderImg),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now the part that I think is most important: the listing part ("listragem" means "listing"). Here I add the items from each feed into a vector and then add them to a ListView and display them on the screen. Here I also put a function to add them to bookmarks, but this is not the problem. My suspicion is that the application waits for this add action to be completed and then the news items appear on the screen.

```
Widget list () {
    List<ListTile> listagem = [];
    
    for (RssFeed f in feeds) {
      for (int i = 0; i < f.items!.length; i++) {
        final item = f.items![i];
        listagem.add(
          ListTile(
            key: ValueKey('${item.link}'),
            title: title(item.title),
            subtitle: subtitle(item.dc?.creator ?? 'No author'),
            leading: thumbnail(item.enclosure!.url),
            trailing: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            onTap: () => openFeed(item.link ?? ''),
          )
        );
      }
    }

    if(listagem.isEmpty) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    else {
      return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listagem.length,
      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
      addRepaintBoundaries: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Slidable(
          startActionPane: ActionPane(
            motion: const DrawerMotion(),
            children: [
              SlidableAction(
                onPressed: (context) {
                  try {
                    BookmarkedPostsController().insert(
                      BookmarkedPostsModel(
                        null,
                        listagem[index].title?.key.toString(),
                        listagem[index].subtitle?.key.toString(),
                        listagem[index].leading?.key.toString(),
                        listagem[index].key.toString(), // the link's in this line
                      )
                    );
                    
                    print(listagem[index].key.toString());
                    
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        dismissDirection: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                        content: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Icon(Icons.bookmark_added, color: Colors.white,),
                            SizedBox(width: 25,),
                            Text(
                              'A notícia foi salva com sucesso!',
                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'San Francisco',),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    );

                    print('Salvou!');
                  }
                  catch (_) {
                    print('Erro!');
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        dismissDirection: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                        content: Row(
                          children: const [
                            Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white,),
                            SizedBox(width: 25,),
                            Text(
                              'Erro: não foi possível salvar a notícia!',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'San Francisco'
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icons.bookmark_outline,
                label: 'Salvar'
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: listagem[index],
        );
      },
    );
    }
  }
```

This function of checking whether or not RSS feeds are empty is a case apart, I have tried leaving it in a "long form", but for some reason I could only make it work this way:

```
isFeedEmpty () {
    return null == feeds || null == feeds.first.items;
  }
```

This last part is the one that loads the body of the application:

```
Widget body () => isFeedEmpty() ?
    const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ) :
    RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () => load(),
      key: _refreshKey,
      child: list(),
    );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Últimas atualizações'),
      ),
      body: body(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried putting a condition so that if the list array is empty, the function returns a CircularProgressIndicator(), but it doesn't seem to work, since, I believe, the error persists until the array is completely filled.

```
if(listagem.isEmpty) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    else {
      return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listagem.length,
```

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens due to no element/data i,e empty values on variable.
So to avoid these issues , assign some values to variable like this.

```
 var title = 'Hello';
```